# Laravel function ignores return

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel application I have a function that is ignoring a return, and it returns the RedirectResponse.
Hear my code.
This is the call:

```
public function updateReservationAPI(Booking $booking)
{
    try {
        $idReturned = $this->getReservationByDate($booking->arrival);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd("Error on API call: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the function:

```
private function getReservationByDate($date, $page = 1)
{
    $dateParam = Carbon::parse($date);
    $url = "https://api.site.url/api/reservations";
    $nextPage = "";

    if (Session::has('access_token')) {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->get($url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'JWT ' . Session::get('access_token'),
            ],
            'query' => [
                'page' => $page,
            ],
        ]);

        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        if ($statusCode === 200) {
            $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            $data = json_decode($body, true);

            $nextLink = $data["next"];
            if (!is_null($nextLink)) {
                $parsedUrl = parse_url($nextLink);
                parse_str($parsedUrl['query'], $queryParams);
                $nextPage = $queryParams['page'];
            }
            $results = $data['results'];

            $idToReturn = null;
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $dataItem = Carbon::parse($result["register_date"]);

                if ($dateParam->isSameDay($dataItem)) {
                    $idToReturn = $result["id"];
                    return $idToReturn;
                }

            }
            if (!is_null($nextLink)) {
                return $this->getReservationByDate($date, $nextPage);
            }
        }

    } else {
        $this->loginAPI();
        $this->getReservationByDateAPI($date, $page);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I would to return the id found on `if ($dateParam->isSameDay($dataItem))` statement but I get an `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` response.

If I try to put `dd($idToReturn)` just before the return, I get the expected data.

Comment: In your ```updateReservationAPI(Booking $booking){..}``` function, have yo try to add *return*? Like ```try { $idReturned = $this->getReservationByDate($booking->arrival); return $idReturned}``` ? I think *dd* is return *$idToReturn* but *return* just throw error because as it try to pass the value, no one will get em.

Comment: then why have you added ``return redirect()->back();`` ?

Comment: I tried to remove `return redirect()->back();` but it returns `null` value even if the `dd($idToReturn)` just before the return get the right value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because of the `return redirect()->back();` statement that you have at the end of the function. This statement will always be executed if none of the conditions inside the function match, leading to a redirection.

Comment: Even if I remove the `return redirect()->back();` statement it returns `null` instead of the value that I got with `dd()` before the return.

Answer (score 0):

check type of returned

```
    $result = $reservation = $this->getReservationByDate($data);
    if (get_class($result) === 'Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse') return $result ;
```

else $reservation model !

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that your path leading to your ideal return is not true.

So it will be one of these issues:

- Session does not have access token
- The status code of the request is not 200
- Results is empty (so $data['results'] is empty or null)

You can use `dd()` to dump the data at various points in the code to try and work out which one of those is returning false.

Comment: I tried a dd() just before the return and it gave me the correct value, so the issue is not there...